# How to make a dynamic table in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have 2 tables in excel like

```
In Table:
Product1    50
Product2    75
...

Out Table
Product1   25
PRoduct3   40
...
```

And i would wish for a third table that will automaticly update when i add new rows in In or Out Tables (like a PivotTable or something similar) in to:

```
Current Table
Product1  25
Product2  35
...
```

Anyone has any ideea how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a formula in each cell in Current Table to calculate the difference between the corresponding cells in the other two tables.

[image: Input, Output, and Current table, with Formula bar showing difference formula]

Comment: I wish that Current Table will update with new rows when i add new rows in In or Out tables, something like a PivotTable, but for some reason i can't use formulas when 2 tables are in a Relationship in Pivottable

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. When I expand the height of each table, the formulas in the Current Table are copied down, so with two steps, I think I get the result you want: 1) expand tables, 2) add data to In/Out tables. Is this good enough? Or do you want to avoid having to expand the Current table?

Comment: It would be ideal to avoid having to expand the current table. Also at some point In/Out Tables would have different number of rows.